# How to update php5.6-curl so that it can validate new LetsEncrypt X1 certificates?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, server, libcurl

*(I know this question may not be right place for stackoverflow, except that it DOES have programming implications, and possibly a programming solution)*

Since the LetsEncrypt X3 expiry, all new certificates are being signed by X1. Older systems fail to validate this new certificate. Including ondrej's php5.6-curl module for ubuntu 14.04.

We've managed to install openssl 1.1.1b which validates the new certificates fine. We've managed to recompile a later version of curl which now also validates the certificates fine.

But php-curl still fails.  I know the best solution is to get off ubuntu14.04/php5.6 but its not an option right now. Does anyone know how I might get php5.6-curl working with the new X1 certificates?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a relatively new version (8.0.8) of php on an old OS (macOS 10.13), I had to build PHP from scratch with the new curl to get this working.

Comment: Yea i was afraid of that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions on this page worked for me to update certs on php5.6... https://support.deskpro.com/lt-LT/kb/articles/how-to-update-curl-trusted-root-certificates

Comment: Ahh that makes total sense! Thank you!